# jQuery partial view detect row

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My application consists of a single form which has a partial view in it which allows to me add or remove rows dynamically through the use of jQuery and ajax.

[image]

Each row contains multiple form elements, one of which is a button which then loads a modal (stored in my main view) which allows the user to search and select a certain vendor.Once the user has selected a certain vendor, I then store this selection in a variable and display it in a text field of that same row.

The problem I now face: **I have no idea how to identify which row (=instance of the partial view) the user is currently in.**

**Main View which includes my partial view:**

```
...
    <tbody id="OrderZone">
    @foreach (var row in Model.ExtendedOrders)
    {
       Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Orders/OrderExtendedCreate.cshtml", row);   
    }
    </tbody>
...
```

**Partial View:**

```
    <tr class="editorRow">
        @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("ExtendedOrders"))
        {
            //other form elements..

            <td style="min-width:250px">
                <div class="input-group vendorGroup">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default vendorButton" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                    </span>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Vendor, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "input-sm form-control vendor" } })
                </div>
            </td>

            //other form elements..
        }
    </tr>
```

I've included the JavaScript code below in my partial view. I first store whichever button (the one that opens the modal) the user clicked. Then I look for the input field (vendor) which shares the same parent with that button.  However, this solution doesn't seem to work. It just selects the first row every time:

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
        var searchButtonVendor = $('.editorRow').find(".vendorButton");
        searchButtonVendor.click(function () {
            var modalResultShouldComeHere = $(this).parents('.vendorGroup').find(".vendor");
        });  
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expectation is to get the row content of the respective button. You need to use "closest" selector. This will traverse to top and get first matching element.

Change your code as follows

```
var searchButtonVendor = $('.editorRow').find(".vendorButton");
    searchButtonVendor.click(function () {
        var modalResultShouldComeHere = $(this).closest('.vendorGroup').find(".vendor");
    });
```

The below will get the current row. You need to modify to get the selected item from model to text box in a row.

```
var modalResultShouldComeHere = $(this).closest('.vendorGroup').find(".vendor");
```

Comment: Thank you! Finally managed to get this to work, was driving me nuts for hours!!

Comment: by this method you could take the vendor value only

Answer (score 1):

You can get the currently clicked search row complete(three) data by the below code

```
$('.vendorButton').click(function(){
    var VendorID = $(this).closest('tr').find('td')[1].childNodes[1].id;
    var vendorValue = $('#'+VendorID).val();
    var OrderCodeID = $(this).closest('tr').find('td')[2].childNodes[0].id;
    var OrderCodeValue = $('#' + OrderCodeID).val();
    var PriceID = $(this).closest('tr').find('td')[3].childNodes[0].id;
    var PriceValue = $('#' + PriceID).val();
});
```

hope this helps